# How to trigger click event in new browser tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I opened a new browser tab using below code, In the new browser tab I have `<span class="refresh-table-data"></span>` element which work as a button and clicking on it trigger ajax which updates table with latest data, Now when I change the focus back to this tab I want to trigger click on that tab so that table data gets updated via ajax but it is not working.

```
    var newWin = window.open(url, '_blank');

    newWin.addEventListener('focus', function() {
      var refreshBtnList = newWin.document.getElementsByClassName('refresh-table-data');
      for (var idx=0; idx < refreshBtnList.length; idx++) {
        refreshBtnList[idx].click(); // Here I'm getting span element properly but click is not getting trigger by this code
      }
    });
```

I can see the element in the developer tools window as below.

[image]

Please suggest what I'm missing here?

Comment: Instead of faking events in the DOM extract the logic that loads the data out to its own function and call that directly.

Answer (score 1):

Call trigger `click` everytime when window has focus, something like this ( to test it, just click outside of snippet and again on snippet container ).

P.S: also you can try to play with `document.hasFocus()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
    
    var window_focus;
    
    $(window).focus(function() {
        window_focus = true;
      
        $('button').trigger("click");
    
    }).blur(function() {
        window_focus = false;
    });
    
    
    $('button').click(function() {
      // call ajax here:
      $('body').append('has focus<br/>');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click here to begin<br>

<button>
sdf
</button>
```